# Temporary files in container on Azure k8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes, temporary-files

I've a container running code in .NET 6, dockerized and running on Azure k8s.
Inside this container, i handle a message from a topic of a Service Bus.

Scenario description:
I have to call an .exe (size around 90 MB) that take in input a file and generate a response in a given physical subfolder on disk. The response include two files, that i upload then to a blob storage. Finally i delete these temporary files. There will be around 10k calls in a day, each one with a variable duration from seconds to 1-2 minutes.

Question:
Where should i store the exe? Its content will change 2-3 times a year (so few times). I was thinking to include it in the docker image, for example in \app\resources and then call it creating a random temp folder in the same path, one for each execution. In alternative i was thinking to Azure File Share (but i'm concerned about the traffic cost).
The data is temporary, so if the pod goes down, i don't care about them.

I've already read about volumes in Docker, but i don't find any question/topic that fit my problem, so i'm searching for some advices.

Comment: I think building it into the image is both the simplest and the most sensible solution. Using a temporary directory for ephemeral files and then cleaning it up when you're done is also a very common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to manage temp files inside your container, i would take [tmpfs mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/) Also consider setting a size since it is unlimited by default using  tmpfs-size flag.

Volumes and bind mounts let you share files between the host machine and container so that you can persist data even after the container is stopped.

> If you’re running Docker on Linux, you have a third option: tmpfs
> mounts. When you create a container with a tmpfs mount, the container
> can create files outside the container’s writable layer.
>
> As opposed to volumes and bind mounts, a tmpfs mount is temporary, and
> only persisted in the host memory. When the container stops, the tmpfs
> mount is removed, and files written there won’t be persisted.

Another option you should consider is: [Start a container with a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume) so you have full control, mount,cleanup,delete the volume.